# How to convert the marginal odds ratio to risk difference across different baseline risks?

Tags: r, stata, margins

In `R`, I fitted a logistic regression where the covariate of interest is discrete: treatment effect (data comes from a randomized controlled trial comparing two treatments).

I know how to estimate the population-averaged ("marginal") odds ratio through the parametric G-formula with `R` package `marginaleffects`.

However, my actual goal is to estimate the proportion difference (aka, risk difference or absolute risk reduction/increase) across different baseline risks. Of note, I am not 100% sure this is even possible. Others have suggested this procedure is possible with the `Stata` command `margins` (eg, see this [Twitter thread](https://twitter.com/ProfHayward/status/1559303165719318537?s=20&t=LW78OfHaW4dWBm4bCOavgQ)). I have checked `margins`' documentation but could not figure out how to perform this transformation (marginal OR → ARR across multiple baseline risks).

1- Is this transformation possible?

2 - If so, how could one perform it with R's `marginaleffects`or Stata's `margins`?

See code below for example (more details can be found [here](https://vincentarelbundock.github.io/marginaleffects/articles/gformula.html) and [here](https://vincentarelbundock.github.io/marginaleffects/articles/logistic_contrasts.html):

```r
# Load libraries

library(marginaleffects)
library(rms)
remotes::install_github("jamesotto852/ggdensity")

# Load data

load(url(
  "https://github.com/vincentarelbundock/modelarchive/raw/main/data-raw/gusto.rda"
))

gusto <- subset(gusto, tx %in% c("tPA", "SK"))
gusto$tx <- factor(gusto$tx, levels = c("tPA", "SK"))

# Fit model

mod <- glm(
  day30 ~ tx + rcs(age, 4) + Killip + pmin(sysbp, 120) + lsp(pulse, 50) +
    pmi + miloc + sex, family = binomial(),
  data = gusto)

# Population-averaged (marginal) odds ratio estimated through G-estimation

mOR = 
  comparisons(
  mod,
  variables = "tx",
  transform_pre = "lnoravg",
  transform_post = exp) |>
  summary()

mOR
#>   Term                 Contrast Effect Std. Error z value   Pr(>|z|) 2.5 %
#> 1   tx ln(odds(SK) / odds(tPA))  1.192    0.04489   26.54 < 2.22e-16 1.104
#>   97.5 %
#> 1   1.28
#> 
#> Model type:  glm 
#> Prediction type:  response 
#> Post-transformation:  exp

# Population-averaged (marginal) risk difference estimated through G-estimation

mRD = 
  comparisons(
    mod,
    variables = "tx") |>
  summary()

mRD
#>   Term Contrast  Effect Std. Error z value   Pr(>|z|)    2.5 % 97.5 %
#> 1   tx SK - tPA 0.01108   0.002766   4.005 6.1955e-05 0.005658 0.0165
#> 
#> Model type:  glm 
#> Prediction type:  response

# Patient-specific risk difference

uRD = 
  comparisons(
    mod,
    variables = "tx")

uRD |> 
  ggplot() +
  aes(x = predicted_hi, y = comparison) +
  ggdensity::geom_hdr_points() +
  scale_color_viridis_d(option = "magma", begin = .8, end = 0, direction = -1) +
  labs(x = "Baseline Risk", y = "Risk Difference") +
  theme_minimal()
```

There are over 30 thousand points, thus "probs" show where most of points are located (first, probs == 50%, then 80% and so forth): plot can be found [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TvuKj.png)

```r
sessionInfo()
#> R version 4.1.2 (2021-11-01)
#> Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin17.0 (64-bit)
#> Running under: macOS Catalina 10.15.7
#> 
#> Matrix products: default
#> BLAS:   /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.1/Resources/lib/libRblas.0.dylib
#> LAPACK: /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.1/Resources/lib/libRlapack.dylib
#> 
#> locale:
#> [1] en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/C/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8
#> 
#> attached base packages:
#> [1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     
#> 
#> other attached packages:
#> [1] rms_6.3-0                  SparseM_1.81              
#> [3] Hmisc_4.7-0                ggplot2_3.3.6             
#> [5] Formula_1.2-4              survival_3.3-1            
#> [7] lattice_0.20-45            marginaleffects_0.7.0.9000
#> 
#> loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
#>  [1] viridisLite_0.4.0   splines_4.1.2       assertthat_0.2.1   
#>  [4] highr_0.9           latticeExtra_0.6-29 yaml_2.3.5         
#>  [7] remotes_2.4.2       pillar_1.8.0        backports_1.4.1    
#> [10] quantreg_5.93       glue_1.6.2          digest_0.6.29      
#> [13] RColorBrewer_1.1-3  checkmate_2.1.0     colorspace_2.0-3   
#> [16] sandwich_3.0-2      htmltools_0.5.2     Matrix_1.4-1       
#> [19] pkgconfig_2.0.3     purrr_0.3.4         mvtnorm_1.1-3      
#> [22] scales_1.2.0        jpeg_0.1-9          MatrixModels_0.5-0 
#> [25] htmlTable_2.4.0     tibble_3.1.8        farver_2.1.1       
#> [28] generics_0.1.3      TH.data_1.1-1       withr_2.5.0        
#> [31] nnet_7.3-17         cli_3.3.0           magrittr_2.0.3     
#> [34] polspline_1.1.20    evaluate_0.15       fs_1.5.2           
#> [37] fansi_1.0.3         nlme_3.1-158        MASS_7.3-57        
#> [40] foreign_0.8-82      tools_4.1.2         data.table_1.14.3  
#> [43] lifecycle_1.0.1     multcomp_1.4-19     stringr_1.4.0      
#> [46] munsell_0.5.0       reprex_2.0.1        cluster_2.1.3      
#> [49] ggdensity_0.1.0.900 compiler_4.1.2      rlang_1.0.4        
#> [52] grid_4.1.2          rstudioapi_0.13     htmlwidgets_1.5.4  
#> [55] labeling_0.4.2      base64enc_0.1-3     rmarkdown_2.14     
#> [58] gtable_0.3.0        codetools_0.2-18    DBI_1.1.3          
#> [61] curl_4.3.2          R6_2.5.1            gridExtra_2.3      
#> [64] zoo_1.8-10          knitr_1.39          dplyr_1.0.9        
#> [67] fastmap_1.1.0       utf8_1.2.2          insight_0.18.0.4   
#> [70] stringi_1.7.6       vctrs_0.4.1         rpart_4.1.16       
#> [73] png_0.1-7           tidyselect_1.1.2    xfun_0.31
```

<sup>Created on 2022-08-15 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

I applied simple math related to "probability" and "odds", and came up with [these results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eUM2v.png). Not sure if it's correct:

```r
# Load libraries

library(marginaleffects)
library(rms)
#> Loading required package: Hmisc
#> Loading required package: lattice
#> Loading required package: survival
#> Loading required package: Formula
#> Loading required package: ggplot2
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'Hmisc'
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:base':
#> 
#>     format.pval, units
#> Loading required package: SparseM
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'SparseM'
#> The following object is masked from 'package:base':
#> 
#>     backsolve

# Load data

load(url(
  "https://github.com/vincentarelbundock/modelarchive/raw/main/data-raw/gusto.rda"
))

gusto <- subset(gusto, tx %in% c("tPA", "SK"))
gusto$tx <- factor(gusto$tx, levels = c("tPA", "SK"))

# Fit model

mod <- glm(
  day30 ~ tx + rcs(age, 4) + Killip + pmin(sysbp, 120) + lsp(pulse, 50) +
    pmi + miloc + sex, family = binomial(),
  data = gusto)

# Population-averaged (marginal) odds ratio estimated through G-estimation

mOR = 
  comparisons(
  mod,
  variables = "tx",
  transform_pre = "lnoravg",
  transform_post = exp) |>
  summary()


p = seq(0, 1, 0.01)

odds_t = (mOR$estimate*(p/(1-p)))

p_t = odds_t/(1 + odds_t)
RD = p_t  - p

plot(x = p,
     y = RD,
     xlab = "Baseline Risk",
     ylab = "Risk Difference")
```

<sup>Created on 2022-08-15 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>